# how can i get the code id from FacebookApiException $e?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

how can i get the code id from `FacebookApiException $e`?

I am using Facebook to post. but sometimes it fails to post the content. I am using these codes below, and I find the error response code id in array `$e`, but all them are protected, how can i get the code then?

```
try{
    $facebook->setAccessToken($access_token);
    $rs= $facebook->api('/me/feed','POST',$post_data);
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    print_r($e);
}
```

then I get the error info:

```
FacebookApiException Object
(
    [result:protected] => Array
        (
            [error] => Array
                (
                    [message] => Invalid OAuth access token.
                    [type] => OAuthException
                    [code] => 190  // I need this code
                )

        )

    [message:protected] => Invalid OAuth access token.
    [string:private] => 
    [code:protected] => 0
    [file:protected] => D:\phpnow\htdocs\laji\facebook-php-sdk\base_facebook.php
    [line:protected] => 1267
    [trace:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [file] => D:\phpnow\htdocs\laji\facebook-php-sdk\base_facebook.php
                    [line] => 876
                    [function] => throwAPIException
                    [class] => BaseFacebook
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [error] => Array
                                        (
                                            [message] => Invalid OAuth access token.
                                            [type] => OAuthException
                                            [code] => 190
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [file] => D:\phpnow\htdocs\laji\facebook-php-sdk\base_facebook.php
                    [line] => 650
                    [function] => _graph
                    [class] => BaseFacebook
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => /me/feed
                            [1] => POST
                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [access_token] => 1CAACg13jYHp8BAP0QEOK8PwC7ZCMnSa1tAQclbRJpcNP1zQIBnB1to6etQ2wb8wiVcETDvT5dRZAUiNiZBFvt1RYgo5xUe1do4yeY5DxKIjjDBbElI8zZBBlz5yHRwigIcNYtyhHY9ZAtHL16ZAMPyo43wZANhGWE6o6EV7hXZBtxBEN24xTlGa7M
                                    [picture] => http://imgjy.com/FPB470/m/5236e26acc73a.jpg
                                    [link] => http://www.persunmall.com/persun/giveaway02.html?refer_id=1900
                                    [name] => my all_prams link <name>7458
                                )

                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [file] => D:\phpnow\htdocs\laji\fb_post.php
                    [line] => 98
                    [function] => api
                    [class] => BaseFacebook
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Facebook Object
                                        (
                                            [sharedSessionID:protected] => 
                                            [appId:protected] => 176847305842335
                                            [appSecret:protected] => f79311ddff5888a165d46159b06f4670
                                            [user:protected] => 
                                            [signedRequest:protected] => 
                                            [state:protected] => 
                                            [accessToken:protected] => 
                                            [fileUploadSupport:protected] => 
                                            [trustForwarded:protected] => 
                                        )

                                    [1] => _graph
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => /me/feed
                                    [1] => POST
                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [access_token] => 1CAACg13jYHp8BAP0QEOK8PwC7ZCMnSa1tAQclbRJpcNP1zQIBnB1to6etQ2wb8wiVcETDvT5dRZAUiNiZBFvt1RYgo5xUe1do4yeY5DxKIjjDBbElI8zZBBlz5yHRwigIcNYtyhHY9ZAtHL16ZAMPyo43wZANhGWE6o6EV7hXZBtxBEN24xTlGa7M
                                            [picture] => http://imgjy.com/FPB470/m/5236e26acc73a.jpg
                                            [link] => http://www.persunmall.com/persun/giveaway02.html?refer_id=1900
                                            [name] => my all_prams link <name>7458
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/exception-getResult/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having tried it, wouldn't this work?

```
echo "Code: " . $e["error"]["code"];
```

Answer (score 0):

What i understand in you query is you want code id i.e   **[code] => 190**
see here we are using **FacebookApiException** class
which have following method

```
**[0] => __construct
[1] => getResult
[2] => getType
[3] => __toString
[4] => getMessage
[5] => getCode
[6] => getFile
[7] => getLine
[8] => getTrace
[9] => getPrevious
[10] => getTraceAsString**

so from your code  

try{
$facebook->setAccessToken($access_token);
$rs= $facebook->api('/me/feed','POST',$post_data);
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    print_r($e);
}

as per your code 


you can do two thing

1. 

       try{
            $facebook->setAccessToken($access_token);
            $rs= $facebook->api('/me/feed','POST',$post_data);
        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {

           echo $e->getCode(); //which is the 5th method of the class

        }

or you can simply get all response like 

2. 


    try{
            $facebook->setAccessToken($access_token);
            $rs= $facebook->api('/me/feed','POST',$post_data);
        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {

           $result = $e->getResult(); //which is the 1st method of the class and provide you all response 
    //so for getting the code only 

    echo $result['error']['code'];

        }
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

According to the facebook doc. I'm not sure if this help.

```
$result = $e->getResult();
error_log(json_encode($result));
```

Please follow : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/exception-getResult