# PHP Facebook SDK - Exception - catch error code (without message)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, exception

I want get the error code from Facebooks exception message - without doing some hacky explode/workaround. My code:

```
try {
    // some fb api method
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e; // Outputs i.e. "OAuthException: (#200) Cannot send notifications to a user who has not installed the app"
    echo $e->getCode(); // Ouputs "0". Expected: "200"
}
```

I do notice, by doing a `var_dump($e)` that the object does contain the code - but I have no idea how to catch it, since it is protected.

FYI, this is how `$e` looks like:

```
FacebookApiException Object
(
    [result:protected] => Array
        (
            [error] => Array
                (
                    [message] => (#100) Must specify a non-empty template param
                    [type] => OAuthException
                    [code] => 100
                )

        )

    [message:protected] => (#100) Must specify a non-empty template param
    [string:Exception:private] => 
    [code:protected] => 0
    [file:protected] => /data/home/my_project/public_html/php-sdk/base_facebook.php
    [line:protected] => 1271
    [trace:Exception:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /data/home/my_project/public_html/php-sdk/base_facebook.php
                    [line] => 880
                    [function] => throwAPIException
                    [class] => BaseFacebook
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [error] => Array
                                        (
                                            [message] => (#100) Must specify a non-empty template param
                                            [type] => OAuthException
                                            [code] => 100
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [function] => _graph
                    [class] => BaseFacebook
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => /fb_user_id/notifications
                            [1] => POST
                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [template] => 
                                    [href] => transfer=
                                    [access_token] => my_app_id|my_app_secret
                                )

                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /data/home/my_project/public_html/php-sdk/base_facebook.php
                    [line] => 654
                    [function] => call_user_func_array
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Facebook Object
                                        (
                                            [sharedSessionID:protected] => 
                                            [appId:protected] => my_app_id
                                            [appSecret:protected] => my_app_secret
                                            [user:protected] => 
                                            [signedRequest:protected] => 
                                            [state:protected] => 
                                            [accessToken:protected] => 
                                            [fileUploadSupport:protected] => 
                                            [trustForwarded:protected] => 
                                        )

                                    [1] => _graph
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => /fb_user_id/notifications
                                    [1] => POST
                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [template] => 
                                            [href] => transfer=
                                            [access_token] => my_app_id|my_app_secret
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /data/home/my_project/public_html/core/controllers/edu-cron.php
                    [line] => 524
                    [function] => api
                    [class] => BaseFacebook
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => /fb_user_id/notifications
                            [1] => POST
                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [template] => 
                                    [href] => transfer=
                                    [access_token] => my_app_id|my_app_secret
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [previous:Exception:private] => 
)
```

Comment: Have you tried/read this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21326411/how-can-i-get-the-code-id-from-facebookapiexception-e

Comment: No, I havent. But I tried the suggested solution already. It gives me an error: `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type FacebookApiException as array`

Comment: This *is* a duplicate, but if the earlier question has been answered and accepted, but the accepted solution does not work for this duplicate, what is the protocol here?

Comment: Well, I notice second answer in linked post suggest this solution- but it is not the "accepeted solution".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this too?

```
$result = $e->getResult(); //which is the 1st method of the class and provide you all response 
//so for getting the code only 

echo $result['error']['code'];
```

I can't answer in comment.